# How to deny read access to only a particular child node (user) of parent node "users" in firebase real-time database?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My database structure is:

```
root
    |_users

        |_ user0
        |_ user1  x
        |_ user2
        |_ . . .
```

I want to deny data read for user1 only.
Means, read with following paths should NOT be denied :

```
/
/users
/users/user0
/users/user2
```

I tried this out, but it will not work on data read with /users path

```
{
    "rules": {
        "$allreferences": {
            ".read":true,
        },
        "users": {
            "$allusers": {
                ".read":" $allusers !== \"user1\" "
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try to use this code

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      "user1": {
        ".read": false
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of a named rule and a wildcard rule for this:

```
"users": {
    "user1": {
        ".read": false
    },
    "$other": {
        ".read": true
    }
}
```

Note though that you now won't be able to read directly from `/users` and will instead have to read each individual user node. This is because any permission you grant on `/users` would [cascade downwards](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/core-syntax#read_and_write_rules_cascade) to **all** child nodes, and there's no way to implement an exception to this rule.